# 50 W Charger USB-PD Integration and Simulation

Tags: simulation, charger, usb-pd

I'm designing a charger for a smartphone. I designed a [circuit](https://ibb.co/3dqwg8q) that will take 20 V 2.5 A at the output by following the USB-PD protocols required for 50 W through an internet-based simulation program offered by STMicroelectronics. However, I need to integrate sync rectifier controller and USB-PD controller into this circuit as in the [picture](https://ibb.co/CHG7GDM).

1. How do I integrate them?
2. I need a program for PC (Windows) to simulate this circuit to measure output and input, which one should I use?

Comment: Start by adding data sheet links to the parts in the 2nd picture. Then follow that up reading how the secondary sync rectifier chip works. Then if your output is 20 volts, you'll probably find that all the extra work to add the sync rectifier is probably just not worth the effort and that the gains are low.